# How to add dynamic tabs and dynamic expandable list view inside it in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I just want to create a tabs dynamically according to the number category available. Inside each tab I need to create a number of Expandable list views dynamically inside the each tab. (Example: say I got four categories like education, sports, science, aerospace) then I need to create four tabs on run time, it will change according to the number categories I am getting (one or twenty or more).

Inside each tab I need to create number of expandable list views (dynamically).

After much research, I found some related links ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353132/dynamic-tab-in-android-with-dynamic-tab-content), [here](https://kandroid.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/tabview-part-1-simple-tab-control-in-android/), [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip) and more). I would prefer to go with the proper and efficient method which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

you need to consider as like this

TAB2 = TAB3 = TAB1 = Fragement---- In this you can do expandable listview which will be defined in layout itself but with the reference of TAB'S you need to Update the expandable listview.

For dynamic Tabview you can do like this
You should specify a TabSpec either by specifying

the id of a View, or
a TabHost.TabContentFactory that creates the View content
Your code does both!

Change your code to one of the following:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
   final String tabName = "tab" + Integer.toString(i);
   final TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
   ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() { 
      public View createTabContent(String tag) { 
          TextView text = new TextView(NewTicket.this);
          String tabText = tabName;
          text.setText("You've created a new tab " + tabText); 
          return (text);
      }
   });
   ourSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
   tabhost.addTab(ourSpec);
  }

or

 for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
   final String tabName = "tab" + Integer.toString(i);
   final TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
   ourSpec.setContent(R.id.llItemList);   
   ourSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
    tabhost.addTab(ourSpec);
  }
```

To preserve the same instance of ListView, as mentioned in your comment, do the following:

Register a TabHost.OnTabChangeListener
When the tab changes, you should first call removeView() on the ListView's current parent and then addView() it to the new parent.